# Updating an object in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update a object in an array that is two-way binded to a directive but its not working at all.

I am doing the following to update it:

```
   $filter('filter')
        ($scope.offers, {id: offer_id})[0].status = "active";
```

I get no console errors but if I console.log $scope.offers after the filter code is executed, the status is not updated.

What I am trying to accomplish is to update an object in $scope.offers array with a new value. Every object in the array has a `id` attribute that is unique which I am trying to select it by.

Hope this information is sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: `filter` isn't used to modify objects

Comment: Oh.. I found a stack overflow post of somebody trying to accomplish what i was doing use Filter. I guess I should of checked the documentation. Would you happen to know how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are updating the status of outcome of the filter expression.

That means `$filter('filter')($scope.offers, {id: offer_id})` itself returns an array. And you are updating that array, not the actual array.

I believe, `$scope.offers` is two way binded and you are not updating it.

I hope this makes some sense. And if you can explain what exactly you want. Then I can put some more light.

**EDIT**

So, i think once you get the new status value and the id on which you need to update. You can simply iterate the array using simple `for` loop and check for id and if it matches update the status. Something like this.

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id === requiredId) {
        array[i].status = newStatus;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I have updated the post with more information on what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can check that.

Comment: I was trying to find a utility function to accomplish this instead of having to write a loop but I'll use this to get it working and refactor later. Sorry for the confusing post. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: In that case, you can create a custom filter and pass the id and new status into it. And you can add this loop inside that custom filter. But make sure you update the actual model with the output of filter.

Answer (score 0):

Using native JS methods the `updateArrObj` function below utilizes [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to search for an object that matches the specified `id` and then using a more generic update approach will map an update object onto the original object. The main benefit of using `some` is twofold: you get a boolean value to indicate if an update occurred and also it will stop searching the array after it makes an update.

```
function updateArrObj(arr, id, update) {
  return arr.some(function findObj(obj) {
   if (obj.id === id) {
     Object.keys(update).forEach(function updateObj(key) {
       obj[key] = update[key];
     });

     return true;
   }
  });
}
```

```js
var arrObj = [
  {id: 1, status: 'inactive'},
  {id: 2, status: 'inactive'},
  {id: 3, status: 'inactive'},
  {id: 4, status: 'inactive'},
  {id: 5, status: 'inactive'}
];

var updated = updateArrObj(arrObj, 3, {status: 'active'});

document.write(
  '<h3>Updated: ' + updated + '</h3>' +
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrObj, null, 4) + '</pre>'
);

function updateArrObj(arr, id, update) {
  return arr.some(function findObj(obj) {
   if (obj.id === id) {
     Object.keys(update).forEach(function updateObj(key) {
       obj[key] = update[key];
     });
     
     return true;
   }
  });
}
```